# Pythonl lxml adding linebreak between specific nodes when creating xml file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am writing an XML file using lxml. I am able to write the entire XML file to one line:

```
<FIXML><Batch Total="3"><Hdr SendTime="2016-09-27T13:32:19-05:00"/><RepeatingNode Price="0.99" RptID="1"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode><RepeatingNode Price="2.49" RptID="2"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode><RepeatingNode Price="0.25" RptID="3"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode></Batch></FIXML>
```

and I am able to pretty_print it using the pretty_print parameter:

```
<FIXML>
    <Batch Total="3">
        <Hdr SendTime="2016-09-27T13:32:19-05:00"/>
        <RepeatingNode Price="0.99" RptID="1">
            <Date Dt="2016-09-20"/>
        </RepeatingNode>
        <RepeatingNode Price="2.49" RptID="2">
            <Date Dt="2016-09-20"/>
        </RepeatingNode>
        <RepeatingNode Price="0.25" RptID="3">
            <Date Dt="2016-09-20"/>
        </RepeatingNode>
    </Batch>
</FIXML>
```

However, I would like to write to my file and add a linebreak only after each ReapeatingNode. I would also like to avoid any indentation. My ideal output file would look like this:

```
<FIXML>
<Batch Total="3">
<Hdr SendTime="2016-09-27T13:32:19-05:00"/>
<RepeatingNode Price="0.99" RptID="1"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode>
<RepeatingNode Price="2.49" RptID="2"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode>
<RepeatingNode Price="0.25" RptID="3"><Date Dt="2016-09-20"/></RepeatingNode>
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

Below is the framework for my code:

```
import lxml.etree as et
fixml_node = et.Element("FIXML")
batch_node = et.SubElement(fixml_node, "Batch")
et.SubElement(batch_node, "Hdr")

for row in data:
    repeating_node = et.SubElement(batch_node, "RepeatingNode")
    et.SubElement(repeating_node, "Date")

complete_new_file = et.ElementTree(fixml_node)

complete_new_file.write("output_file")

# or below when pretty-printing
complete_new_file.write("output_file", pretty_print=True)
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is to ignore the pretty_print param and add a text or tail with a linebreak where applicable. New code below:

```
import lxml.etree as et

fixml_node = et.Element("FIXML")
fixml_node.text = "\n"

batch_node = et.SubElement(fixml_node, "Batch")
batch_node.text = "\n"
batch_node.tail = "\n"

header_node = et.SubElement(batch_node, "Hdr")
header_node.tail = "\n"

for row in data:
    repeating_node = et.SubElement(batch_node, "RepeatingNode")
    repeating_node.tail = "\n"

    et.SubElement(repeating_node, "Date")

complete_new_file = et.ElementTree(fixml_node)

complete_new_file.write("output_file")
```

This is an easy way to customize the positioning of linebreaks throughout the file. I'll leave this question open for a day or two to see if anyone has a better solution.